# rxjs unsubscription happening despite catching the error

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am having an event emitter `testEvent`. `testEvent` has a pipe chain and in that chain an error is thrown. But I am also catching the error at two places in the chain. Despite that my `testEvent` is automatically being unsubscribed.

Can someone explain why?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqz4zs?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {catchError, switchMap} from 'rxjs/internal/operators';
import {forkJoin, of} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  testEvent$ = new EventEmitter();
  ngOnInit(){
    this.testEvent$
    .pipe(
       map((x) => {
         alert();
         throw "error";
       },
       catchError((e)=>{
         console.log(e);
         return of(1);
       })
       )
     )
     .subscribe(null, (e)=>{
       console.log(e);
     })
  }

  test(){
    this.testEvent$.emit(''); //works only once
  }


}
```

Comment: Use an RXJS subject, not an eventemitter

Comment: ya..but my question is why not working

Comment: You emit one value right? So that is all the subscription will do. Subjects will keep emitting new values on change.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is you return `of(1)` in your error handler. The subscription then resubscribes to that Observable, which only emits once. It no longer is subscribed to the `testEvent$`. Therefore it completes after one emit.

`catchError` callback actually receives original Observable as the second argument. If you want to continue to listen to the original observable, return that from the error handler.

```
catchError((e, originalObservable)=>{
   console.log(e);
   return originalObservable;
})
```

[Working Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nt9tng?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

[RxDocs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError) about the callback:

> a function that takes as arguments err, which is the error, and caught, which is the source observable, in case you'd like to "retry" that observable by returning it again. Whatever observable is returned by the selector will be used to continue the observable chain.

Comment: now I have opposite of the original problem. Subscribing to original observable is causing recursion. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vf3fxt?file=src/app/app.component.ts
Any idea why?

Comment: @asdasd Of course it's causing a recursion. You have an Observable that immediately throws and catches an error and then switches to itself which repeats the process. But I don't think that this is your real code / problem. You should post your real code or give a better insight into what your actual problem is or what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It causes recursion on __cold__ observables. On hot ones, it re-listens. To avoid recursion, catch errors directly map/switchMap and similar operators.

Answer (score 1):

If you throw an error in `map` this error is propagated through the `onError` channel which **terminates** the sequence. With `catchError` you catch this error and move on to the next sequence `of(1)`, but the first sequence in which the error occurred is still terminated.

> In an Observable Execution, zero to infinite Next notifications may be
>   delivered. If either an Error or Complete notification is delivered,
>   then **nothing else can be delivered afterwards**.
>   [RxJS: Executing Observables](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable#executing-observables)

If you don't want the first Observable to terminate you shouldn't throw an error as errors can't occurr multiple times thoughout the lifetime of an Observable.